# AG Grid - CellRender - Read CheckBox Value

Tags: angular, ag-grid

In AG Grid, Using CellRender - I have shown a checkbox in the grid column using the template as shown below

```
cellRenderer = (params) => {
    if ((params.data.IsReview != undefined) && (params.data.IsReview  == true)) { 
        return '<input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" ';
    }
```

Once User select's the checkbox in UI, how do I get the values of the checkbox, Since its not directly bind to grid data model, how can i read the check box value from cell render template?

Comment: Basically, you should read a little bit about [angular binding](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)

Comment: in order to use anything more than plain html in cell renderer, you will have to create a cell renderer component than a function